# CloudFront 502 Error DomainName Issue not resolving

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm using S3 as a static host website and Cloudfront. Building this with Cloudformation and Ansible.
There's something wrong with the DomainName. In the console, when you choose the origin domain, it shows you the bucket name first(which is the alternate domain name) and it resolves to the same value that I have in CloudFormation. No 502 error when I change it in the console.
Also, how do you set OAI when using CustomOriginConfig in CloudFront? I only see it with S3Origin property.

````
  SourceBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: {{ S3.Bucket }}
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: index.html
      VersioningConfiguration:
        Status: Enabled
      BucketEncryption: 
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration: 
        - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
            SSEAlgorithm: AES256

  WebsiteCDN:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Comment: CDN for S3-backed website
        Aliases:
         - !Ref SourceBucket
        Enabled: "true"
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          Compress: true
          TargetOriginId: testid-origin
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: "true"
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        Origins:
        - DomainName: !Join ['', [!Ref SourceBucket, ".s3.", !Ref 'AWS::Region', ".amazonaws.com"]]
          CustomOriginConfig:
            HTTPPort: '80'
            HTTPSPort: '443'
            OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
          Id: testid

main.yml
S3:
  Bucket: "test-uat12.<domain>.com.au"
```[Here's how it look like in the Console.. I removed the domain name in the code for security purposes.][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUPNl.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved this by using s3origin instead of customorigin.